# Как получить информацию о скинах на акаунте стим (node.js)

Tags: node.js, парсер, steam

Начинаю изучать js, задался вопросом через какой запрос можно получить всю информацию по скенами на аке Steam? Через post запрос нужен API, этот вариант не подходит. Хочу написать простой парсер. Мне интересно как получают информацию сайты обменники? У них же нет Steam API моего ака.

Comment: Если вы начали учить js, то вы слишком далеко полезли. Уча таблицу умножения, крайне сложно "вычислить" интеграл. Про Steam и прочее - не факт, что steam не предоставляет коммерческие апи где есть всё.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/steam и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/steam